# Disabling Md-(prev/next)-buttons in md-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I have the following angular material tab:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-stretch-tabs="never" md-no-bar md-no-ink id="tabcontainer" md-selected="tabdata.selectedIndex" md-no-ink class="md-padding" style="padding:0px; width:100%">
    <md-tab label="Tab1">
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab2">
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Tab3">
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

In its first load, `md-prev-button` and `md-next-button` become visible at the left and right hand side of my tab bar and after approximately 1 second directly dissappear. These are used in tab bar to navigate between tab names but it is totally unnecessary since i have enough space to show all the tab names.

They are also becoming visible when i resize the page a little although i have again enough space for all tab names.

I could not find a directive to disable that feature in [API](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs). Is there another way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`md-no-pagination`](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs)(`md-no-pagination="true"`)

**When enabled, pagination will remain off**

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="" md-no-pagination="true">
```